# Socrata SODA within polygon is too complex

Tags: socrata

Using the Socrata SODA api for within_polygon an error is thrown stating that it is too complex.

https://www.dallasopendata.com/resource/x9pz-kdq9.json?$where=within_polygon(location,%20%27MULTIPOLYGON%20(((-96.79920%2032.77946,-96.807768%2032.7751,-96.7999%2032.76999,-96.79920%2032.77946)))%27)

```
{
  "code" : "query.execution.queryTooComplex",
  "error" : true,
  "message" : "Only simple comparison filters are allowed",
  "data" : {
    "reason" : "validation.complex-filter"
  }
}
```

Here is a working version:

https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/yama-9had.json?$where=within_polygon(location,%20%27MULTIPOLYGON%20(((-87.63742446899414%2041.871733907393164,-87.64720916748047%2041.8687938398043,-87.6540756225586%2041.86080384272637,-87.64214515686035%2041.85287677909342,-87.63467788696289%2041.859141797891915,-87.62866973876953%2041.86329682898112,-87.63038635253906%2041.86789900978502,-87.64317512512207%2041.86380819876315,-87.64326095581055%2041.86591755588323,-87.63742446899414%2041.871733907393164)))%27)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the old API endpoint, rather than the new one that supports `within_polygon(...)`. You'll want to use [this one instead](http://dev.socrata.com/foundry/#/www.dallasopendata.com/5nug-crr9). The query works as expected against that new endpoint:

```
https://www.dallasopendata.com/resource/5nug-crr9.json?$where=within_polygon(location,%20%27MULTIPOLYGON%20(((-96.79920%2032.77946,-96.807768%2032.7751,-96.7999%2032.76999,-96.79920%2032.77946)))%27)
```

For more details on the migration process, check out [this entry in the API changelog](http://dev.socrata.com/changelog/2015/04/27/new-higher-performance-apis.html).